# Mocking IUserStore against asp.net identity inside asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am trying to unit test my mvc5 app registration action from account controller. In my unit test i try to mock IUserStore but i have some wired casting issues.

```
//inside unit FileName = testegisterationSpecs.cs
var store = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

My ApplicationUser model is following and you can see the inheritance chain.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //[Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}


public class IdentityUser : IUser
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the error I'm getting.

```
The type 'JumpStartPakistan.Web.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'JumpStartPakistan.Web.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>'.   E:\Projects\AspNet\MVC\JumpStartPakistanReboot\JumpStartPakistan\JumpStartPakistan.Tests\Web\Registration\RegisterationSpecs.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.

install this nuget package. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/.  that fixed it for me.